# pipe() between child and parent process

Tags: c, operating-system

I write this code for pipe() between child and parent process. I need to ensure whether this is a correct code or not. By the way it's gives the answer what is suppose to see !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>



int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    pid_t pid;
    int fd[2];
    char buf[20];

pipe(fd);


switch(pid = fork()){

    case -1:
        perror("pipe");
        exit(1);

    case 0: 
        /*child process*/
        close(fd[1]);
        read(fd[0], buf, 20);
        printf("Child read message from parent: %s\n", buf);
        exit(1);
        break;

    default:
     /*parent process*/
        close(fd[0]);
        write(fd[1], "Hello from parent\n", 17);
        break;
    } 
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: This is not a code review site.  What's your question?

Comment: Actually I needed to verify is there any best practices to write these kind of codes. I'm absolute beginner for this operating system stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `switch` statement is mostly ok, although you don't need the `pid` variable since you don't do anything with it.

The parent code is also mostly ok, but the string is actually 18 bytes without the NUL terminator, and 19 bytes with the NUL terminator. It's good practice to handle the newline and NUL terminator in the child, so I would stick with 17 and remove the newline from the string.

The child code is wrong. You need a variable to store the return value from `read`. You need to check the return value to make sure the `read` succeeded. And you need to add a NUL terminator to the string. In the C programming language, a *"string"* is an array of characters that ends with a zero byte (called the NUL terminator, and written as `'\0'`). It's your job to make sure that the buffers you use are always big enough to hold the NUL terminator, and that every string *has* a NUL terminator.

So the fixed code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( void )
{
    int fd[2];
    char buffer[20];

    if ( pipe(fd) < 0 ) {
        perror( "pipe" );
        exit( 1 );
    }

    switch( fork() ) {
        case -1:
            perror( "fork" );
            exit( 1 );

        case 0:
            /*child process*/
            close(fd[1]);
            ssize_t count = read( fd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1 );
            if ( count <= 0 ) {
                perror( "read" );
                exit( 1 );
            }
            buffer[count] = '\0';
            printf( "Child read message from parent: %s\n", buffer );
            exit(1);

        default:
            /*parent process*/
            close(fd[0]);
            char *message = "Hello from parent";
            size_t length = strlen( message );
            write( fd[1], message, length );
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Better I ask this. I forgot about NULL terminator. But I have something to clarify. I thought I've already check the return value to make sure the 'read' succeed at the beginning. if '( pipe(fd) < 0 ) {
        perror( "pipe" );
        exit( 1 );
    }'

Comment: @hasinisilva Checking the return value from `pipe` tells you whether the pipe was created successfully. Under normal conditions, if creating the pipe worked, then the `read` should succeed. But it's good practice to check the return value from `read` anyways. For example, if the parent is stopped by a `SIGSTOP` or `SIGKILL` before it sends the message, then the `read` in the child will fail.

Comment: now I got it. I was misunderstanding that. Anyway I appreciate, you answered me. I could clear so many uncertain points. And the other confusing thing was 'exit(1)'. Why we always use '1' rather than other numeric value. I tried using 0 once. Code was executed without any trouble.

Comment: @hasinisilva The value that you pass to `exit` has no effect inside your program. However, if you call the program from a shell script, then the value is returned to the script. And the script can take different actions depending on whether your program succeeded or failed. Normally, `exit(0)` indicates that the program succeeded, and any other value indicates that the program failed.

Comment: Actually I just got to know it. I used to use exit() without knowing exact thing behind it. It's good to have great help like this. Thanks @user3386109